# How do I extract a specific name between slashes in php?

Tags: php, regex

Let's say I might have a couple of directories stored in a string.. they might look like this

```
/something/WHATEVER/websites/dev/tools/tests/media/upload.ini

/something/WHATEVER/websites/dev/tools/tests/get/add.ini

etc.
```

How can I extract the names "media" and "get" from those two links up there? I would probably have to use regular expressions but how would it look like?

Comment: Why not explode by / and grab the second to last value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use php function explode? http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
$str="one  ,two  ,       three  ,  four    "; 
print_r(array_map('trim',explode(",",$str)));

Output:

Array ( [0] => one [1] => two [2] => three [3] => four )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use regexes, it might look like this

```
/([^/]+)/[^/]+$
```

i.e.,

```
preg_match('`/([^/]+)/[^/]+$`',$fullpath,$matches)
```

`$matches[1]` will contain your directory.

Answer (score 0):

I would normally suggest [`sscanf`](http://php.net/sscanf) for such easy patterns:

```
$string = '/something/WHATEVER/websites/dev/tools/tests/media/upload.ini';
$format = '/something/WHATEVER/websites/dev/tools/tests/%[^/]';
$r = sscanf($string, $format, $name);
```

Next to that there are standard PHP dirname functions that are helpful in case you need this more dynamic, e.g. the last directory name of a filename:

```
$string = '/something/WHATEVER/websites/dev/tools/tests/media/upload.ini';
$reduce = explode('/', dirname($string));
$name = end($reduce);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/dQYVrOM4)